# Sort a String array

Tags: regex, vb.net, linq

I have as input the string in the below format

```vb
"[1_5,3,7,1],[1_2,4,1,9],[],[1_1,,4,,,9,2]"
```

What I need to obtain is the same string but with the number after the `_` sorted:

```vb
"[1_1,3,5,7],[1_1,2,4,9],[],[1_1,2,4,9,,,]"
```

```vb
Dim tmprequestedArea_selectionAreaIn As String = "[1_5,3,7,1],[1_2,4,1,9],[],[1_1,,4,,,9,2]"

tmprequestedArea_selectionAreaIn = Regex.Replace(requestedArea_selectionAreaIn,"\],\[","#")
tmprequestedArea_selectionAreaIn = Regex.Replace(tmprequestedArea_selectionAreaIn,"\[|\]","")

bracList.AddRange(tmprequestedArea_selectionAreaIn.Split(New Char() {"#"c}, StringSplitOptions.None ))

If sortNumber Then 
    'Split braclist by _ and puts the value in strList 
    'If after _ is only one number put only that number, else split it by char "," and put in strList the join of the split by , array
    'Sort the array
    'in previous example strList will contain a,b,c in position 0 and _d_f (instead of f,d) in position 1
    For i As Integer = 0 To bracList.Count -1
        Dim tmp As String()
        Dim tmpInt As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer) 
        If Not(String.IsNullOrEmpty(bracList(i))) Then 
            Dim tmpRequested As String = bracList(i).Split(New Char() {"_"c})(0)
            Dim tmpSelection As String = bracList(i).Split(New Char() {"_"c})(1)

        If tmpSelection.Contains(",") Then
            tmp = tmpSelection.Split(New Char() {","c})
            For j As Integer = 0 To tmp.Length -1
                tmpInt.Add(Convert.toInt32(tmp(j)))
            Next
            tmpInt.Sort
            strList.Add("["  + tmpRequested + "_" + String.Join(",",tmpInt ) + "]")
        Else
            strList.Add("[" +  tmpRequested + "_" + tmpSelection + "]" )
        End If
        Else
            strList.Add("[]")
        End If
    Next i
```

I'm looking for a better way to manage it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, as a possible substitute for what you're doing now.

Given this input string:

```
Dim input As String = "[1_5,3,7,1],[1_2,4,1,9],[],[1_1,,4,,,9,2]"
```

**Note**: this will also deal with decimal values without changes. E.g.,

```
"[1_5.5,3.5,7,1],[1_2.564,4,2.563,9],[],[1_1,,4.23,,,9.0,2.45]"
```

You can extract the content of the brackets with this pattern: `\[(.*?)\]` and use [Regex.Matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches) to return a [MatchCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection) of all the substrings that match the pattern.

Then use a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder) as a container to rebuild the string while the parts are being *treated*.

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Dim pattern As String = "\[(.*?)\]"
Dim matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline)
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

For Each match As Match In matches
    Dim value As String = match.Groups(1).Value
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
        sb.Append("[],")
        Continue For
    End If
    Dim sepPosition As Integer = value.IndexOf("_"c) + 1
    sb.Append("[" & value.Substring(0, sepPosition))
    Dim values = value.Substring(sepPosition).Split(","c)
    sb.Append(String.Join(",", values.Where(Function(n) n.Length > 0).OrderBy(Function(n) CDec(n))))
    sb.Append(","c, values.Count(Function(n) n.Length = 0))
    sb.Append("],")
Next

Dim result As String = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(","c)
```

---

If you don't know about LINQ, this is what it's doing:

```
String.Join(",", values.Where(Function(n) n.Length > 0).OrderBy(Function(n) CDec(n)))
```

**`values`** is an array of strings, generated by `String.Split()`.

**`values.Where(Function(n) n.Length > 0)`**: creates an `Enumerable(Of String)` from `values` **`Where`** the content, **`n`**, is a string of length `> 0`.
I could have written `values.Where(Function(n) Not String.IsNUllOrEmpty(n))`.

**`.OrderBy(Function(n) CDec(n)))`**: Orders the resulting `Enumerable(Of String)` using the string value converted to Decimal and generates an `Enumerable(Of String)`, which is passed back to `String.Join()`, to rebuild the string, adding a char (`","c`) between the parts.

**`values.Count(Function(n) n.Length = 0)`**: Counts the elements of `values` that have `Length = 0` (empty strings). This is the number of empty elements that are *represented* by a comma, appended at the end of the partial string.

Comment: I tried but i take the error Public member 'Where' on type 'String()' not found and i fix replacing [Where]

Comment: It's LINQ. You have to add `Imports System.Linq` on top of your class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a "way" 
I think it is easier to fetch each char of the string and if it is a number you put it in array (and when the char is ']' you start new array) the sort the arrays and replace each number from the string with it's sorted number (so you will just do allocation without the need to reconstruct with regular expression

I wish that I had Visual Studio to provide you the code (it is joyful to code a riddle) ^_^

ps:for the commas you can use a counter for each blank commas an the put it in the end